# Failed to install krew: failed to list the remote URL for index default

Tags: windows, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubectl

When I try to install krew using  [krew.sigs.k8s.io instruction](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/) under WSL2:

```
(
  set -x; cd "$(mktemp -d)" &&
  OS="$(uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" &&
  ARCH="$(uname -m | sed -e 's/x86_64/amd64/' -e 's/\(arm\)\(64\)\?.*/\1\2/' -e 's/aarch64$/arm64/')" &&
  KREW="krew-${OS}_${ARCH}" &&
  curl -fsSLO "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/releases/latest/download/${KREW}.tar.gz" &&
  tar zxvf "${KREW}.tar.gz" &&
  ./"${KREW}" install krew
)
```

And I got an error:

```
failed to list indexes: failed to list the remote URL for index default: command execution failure, output="": exit status 1
```

If that matter, my configuraiton is

- Windows 11
- WSL2 with Kali Linux
- `kubectl` is installed using [multi-step kubernetes.io instruciton](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/)
- `kubectl version` shows `Client Version: v1.29.3`
- `git --version` shows `git version 2.43.0.windows.1`
- `which kubectl` shows `/usr/bin/kubectl`
- `zsh`

I've seen https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/issues/706 but nothing helped from me there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with git permissions and it was sovled with help of [How to correct `git` reporting `detected dubious ownership in repository` without adding `safe.directory` when using WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485958/how-to-correct-git-reporting-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repository-withou)

```
cd ~/.krew/index/default 
git status
```

Output:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//wsl.localhost/kali-linux/home/lislo/.krew/index/default'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///wsl.localhost/kali-linux/home/lislo/.krew/index/default'
```

I've executed the proposed command and re-run installation of krew:

```
(
  set -x; cd "$(mktemp -d)" &&
  OS="$(uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" &&
  ARCH="$(uname -m | sed -e 's/x86_64/amd64/' -e 's/\(arm\)\(64\)\?.*/\1\2/' -e 's/aarch64$/arm64/')" &&
  KREW="krew-${OS}_${ARCH}" &&
  curl -fsSLO "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/releases/latest/download/${KREW}.tar.gz" &&
  tar zxvf "${KREW}.tar.gz" &&
  ./"${KREW}" install krew
)
```

Now kubectl can see krew installed (I've modified path to avoid clashes with windows version of `kubectl.exe`):

```
$ PATH="/bin:$HOME/.krew/bin" kubectl plugin list
The following compatible plugins are available:

/home/lislo/.krew/bin/kubectl-krew
```